# WordPress - add_filter | apply_fitlers

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WooCommerce Plugin in short is a plugin that allows the shop manager to define blocks "Magento style" for each product page.

Example:
For the product X I want the related products block visible and for the product Y I only want to display the upsells block and featured products block.

I'm trying to define a filter so the theme developer can hook some custom blocks.

I have the class WC_Block_Loader

Which has this line of code in the constructor method:

```
   $this->blocks = array()
   $this->blocks = apply_filters('woocommerce_blocks_register', $this->blocks);
   var_dump($this->blocks); //empty
```

In the functions.php of the theme is piece of code below:

```
   function hook_my_custom_wc_blocks ( $blocks ) {
       $blocks['WC_My_Custom_Block'] = get_template_directory().'/includes/blocks/block-my-custom-block.php';
       return $blocks;
   }

   add_filter('woocommerce_blocks_register', 'hook_my_custom_blocks', 10, 1);
```

I think the problem is that I'm initializing the plugin with the 'plugins_loaded' action and the functions.php runs after this hook but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, simply by changing the plugins_loaded hook to the init hook.